# how to dynamically assign numbers to several ids?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This seem like long way of doing things, is it possible to dynamically assign numbers to ids?

```
$(function () {
    $('#Button1').click(function(){
        $('#RegularExpressionValidator1, #RegularExpressionValidator2, #RequiredFieldValidator1, #RequiredFieldValidator2, #RequiredFieldValidator3, #RequiredFieldValidator4, #RequiredFieldValidator5, #RequiredFieldValidator6, #RequiredFieldValidator7, #RequiredFieldValidator8, #RequiredFieldValidator9').css("display", "block");
    });
});
```

These are .NET generated ids which I don't have access to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [attributes starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector. Using it, you can simply do this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#Button1').click(function(){
        $('[id^="RegularExpressionValidator"], [id^="RequiredFieldValidator"]').css("display", "block");
    });
});
```

This will select all elements with an ID starting with `RegularExpressionValidator`. You may want to specify the element type, as well as a container to look in to select fewer elements.

You may also want to use `$.show()` instead of `$.css()`:

```
$('[id^="RegularExpressionValidator"], [id^="RequiredFieldValidator"]').show();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use an "[attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)" selector:

```
$("[id^='RegularExpressionValidator']").css("display", "block");
```

From the jQuery docs:

> This selector can be useful for identifying elements in pages produced
>   by server-side frameworks that produce HTML with systematic element
>   IDs. However it will be slower than using a class selector so leverage
>   classes, if you can, to group like elements.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$(function () {
    $('#Button1').click(function(){
        $('[id^="RegularExpressionValidator"], [id^="RequiredFieldValidator"]').css("display", "block");
    });
});
```